# Is there a way to view the order of include files in xcode

Tags: xcode7, c-preprocessor

I've run into a problem where compilation is failing because a #define is (apparently) not being seen. The easiest way to see what's wrong would be if I could easily view exact order in which header files are being included for a particular C++ file. What's particularly strange is that the code compiles fine under XCode 7.2.1 but fails under XCode 7.3

Is there some way to just invoke the C preprocessor on a source file? That would probably help.

Comment: Open the Help menu and type "preprocess" in the search field.

Answer (score 0):

While I couldn't find a way to see the order of included files, I was able to use the "Perform Action" | "Preprocess..." to view the source file after the C-Preprocessor handled it. By doing the same thing on the machine where compilation was successful, and then using a 'diff' program, I was able to see the problem  (one header existed in two places and the wrong one was being pulled in).

It would certainly have been much easier with a mechanism to just see the source dependency tree though.